# Why is ASP inserting text to name attributes on input elements?

Tags: html, asp.net, validation

So I'm working through validating my forms in asp.net and I noticed the rendered form input elements are changing the "name" attribute from something like `name="firstName"` to `name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtFN"`.

It appears to be grabbing the id of the input element as well as some other text which at this point I can't entirely make sense of.

**For reference:**

***this is the rendered element -***

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtEmail" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_txtEmail" class="reqT">
```

***and this is what I am setting up initially -***

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFN" class="reqT" runat="server" name="firstName"></asp:TextBox>
```

Would anyone be able to clarify:
- the significance of this insert
- is it changeable, and if so what sort of effects does this have

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET does that to insure completely unique names on input elements. You can disable it by changing the `ClientIDMode` to `Static`.

Scott Gu explains a few ways to do that here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

I personally find the `web.config` option to be the easiest:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <pages clientIDMode="Static" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly the explanation I was looking for. Thanks!